# Add shadow on SVG image hover

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a transparent Twitter icon saved as SVG.
Once i add it as img tag and wrap it in link tag like this:

```
<a href="#"><img src="http://imgh.us/twitter_25.svg" width="300"></a>
```

I want to give it a hover effect:
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;

But, the problem is that the image shows with white background and the hover effect gets applied to white background area as well.

```css
a:hover {
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <img src="http://imgh.us/twitter_25.svg" width="300">
</a>
```

Comment: so you want that the shadow to be in your svg  ?

Comment: can you implement the svg as `<svg>`?

Comment: The image is rectangular...what else were you expecting?

Comment: You are not properly targeting the image, try targeting: a:hover img

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe so?

```css
a img {
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: block;
        border: none;
}

a:hover img{
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><img src="http://imgh.us/twitter_25.svg" width="300"></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps drop-shadow might be better...

```css
a:hover img {
  filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 5px #888);
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <img src="http://imgh.us/twitter_25.svg" width="200">
</a>
```